# How do I activate my keymap in my mode?

Tags: major-mode, keymap

Following the
[Mode Tutorial](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeTutorial), 
I /almost/ finished my own mode (my-mode). Now I only have the
problem, that my mode-map settings seem to be ignored:

```
(defvar my-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [(return)] 'newline-and-indent)
    (define-key map [(meta-y)] 'imenu )
    (define-key map [(control-c) (control-c)] 'compile )
    map)
  "Keymap for `my-mode'.")

 ;;;###autoload
(define-derived-mode my-mode fundamental-mode "My"
  "A major mode for editing My files."
  :syntax-table my-mode-syntax-table
  (setq-local comment-start "// ")
  (setq-local comment-end "")
  (setq-local comment-start-skip "\\s<+\\s-*")
  (setq-local font-lock-defaults
              '(my-font-lock-keywords nil t)
              )
  (setq-local tab-width 2)
  (setq-local default-tab-width 2)
  (setq-local indent-line-function 'my-indent-line)
  (setq-local compile-command (my-compiler-command))
  (setq-local imenu-generic-expression
              '((nil "^\\s *EventList\\s +\\(\\sw+\\)" 1)) )
  )
```

The elisp-info tells me that:

```
• The new mode has its own sparse keymap, named `VARIANT-map`.
  `define-derived-mode` makes the parent mode’s keymap the
  parent of the new map, unless `VARIANT-map` is already set and
  already has a parent.
```

So I think that my map should be active. When I open a file that uses
that buffer, `my-mode-map` is defined:

```
my-mode-map is a variable defined in `my.el`.
Its value is (keymap
 (control-c keymap
            (control-c . compile))
 (meta-y . imenu)
 (return . newline-and-indent))
```

But `(describe-key-briefly)` tells me: `C-c C-c` is undefined

On my last post, I made the error that I didn't restart Emacs from
scratch, when reproducing this error. This time I did so and I still
see this behaviour...

Why is my map not active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is active, but your uses of `define-key` are not correct. See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Key-Bindings.html). For example, the correct way to get the `C-c C-c` binding using that syntax is

```
(define-key my-mode-map [(control ?c) (control ?c)] 'compile)
```

Here's IMO a more readable way to do it using `kbd`

```
(defvar my-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "<return>") 'newline-and-indent)
    (define-key map (kbd "M-y") 'imenu)
    (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'compile)
    map)
  "Keymap for `my-mode'.")
```